QGIS - Recent projects list always empty
When opening QGIS, there is never a single project in the recent projects list. Also in the file menu there is never a recent project listed.
What could be causing this?
Warning: this is NOT THE SAME as this question! My recent projects pane is not hidden, it's clearly visible, but always empty.

do you have different profiles?

Not sure what you mean.... on Windows? Probably yes (it's an enterprise machine, although I'm the only user)

QGIS profiles can get corrupted - you can create new profiles to fix - here is some helpful info on this https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-profiles/

@Mapperz, this solves the issue. Could be an accepted answer.

QGIS profiles can get corrupted.
To create a new QGIS profile follow the guide.
https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-profiles/

"A brand new session of QGIS that will open up. That brand new session
will have none of your settings. WHAT? Yeah – you’re running a brand
new “fresh” session of QGIS so you have no settings. No Database
connections. No Plugins. Enjoy the untouched landscape of QGIS."

credit to North River Geographic Systems.
